# Summernote WYSIWYG Editor is not visible

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, user-interface, summernote, bootstrap-wysiwyg

I want to use Summernote editor in a popup that is inside a popup,the popup code is inside the partial view. And i have included the css & js files in the main view but when i click on the editor button popup comes but i am not able to see the editor.I have searched a lot and not able to figure out what can be the issue.Is it because of the popup ??

Comment: how are you loading popup? with ajax?

Comment: This issue got resolved.I initialised the summernote on document.ready and the editor is now visible .

Comment: But the issue with the editor is some of the functionalities are not working .What can be done to make them work?

Comment: what sort of functionalities?

Comment: Like the background color ,insert table ,line height ,font family and style buttons are not working .

Answer (score 0):

Look at this demo I created just now-

http://jsfiddle.net/gze70ov2/1/

First initialize `summernote` on document ready.
And make sure you have included required resources for this to work in order-

- `<link href="font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet"/>`
- `<link href="bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>`
- `<link  href="summernote.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>`
- `<script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`
- `<script src="bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`
- `<script src="summernote.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`